# How to use await with post request in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've a page where I show a list of teams. There's a button to register new teams. You click it and go to the register. There, it does a Http Post to register the team (with the data of the form) and then go back to the page with the list of teams. The problem is, that it goes back before it finish the register of the Http post, so, the new one, is not listed... do you have any idea?

team.page.ts

```
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.teamsService.getTeams().then(data => {
      this.teams = data;
    });
  }
```

newTeam.page.ts

```
async registerTeam(form) {
    let birthDate = this.datepipe.transform(form.dateOfBirth, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    let postData = {
      "name": form.name,
      "description": form.description,
      "hat": 0,
      "birth": birthDate
    }
    await this.teamsService.registerTeam(postData);
    this.router.navigate(['/members/teams']);
  }
```

teams.service.ts

```
getTeams() {
    return this.api.get('GetTeams');
  }

registerTeam(team) {
    return this.api.post('NewTeam', team);
  }
```

api.service.ts

```
  async getHeaders() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + await this.global.getToken()
      })
    };
    return httpOptions;
  }

  async get(route: any) {
    return await this.http.get(this.global.urlAPI + route, await this.getHeaders());
  }

  async post(route: any, postData: any) {
    console.log('Estoy para postear');
    console.log(postData);
    this.http.post(this.global.urlAPI + route, postData, await this.getHeaders()).subscribe(arg => {
      return arg;
    });
  }
```

It's an issue of asyncronity, but I've try many things and don't get with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which `Http` library you are using for making the `POST` request in your service, but you could try subscribing for the response, for example:

```
async registerTeam(form) {
    let birthDate = this.datepipe.transform(form.dateOfBirth, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    let postData = {
      "name": form.name,
      "description": form.description,
      "hat": 0,
      "birth": birthDate
    }
    this.teamsService.registerTeam(postData).subscribe((data) {
      this.router.navigate(['/members/teams']);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm using _HttpClient_. I can't use _subscribe_ because it says _Property doesn't exists on type 'Promise<void>_. I try with _then_ but doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

The [Http Client](https://angular.io/guide/http) returns an observable from `get()` and `post()` requests which can be subscribed to.

```
this.api.post('NewTeam', team).subscribe(response=>{
  // do something with the response
})
```

If you only need to handle the result in your template  you can use the `async` pipe. If you need to do more with the response objects the easiest way to enable `await` would be to use `.toPromise()`

i.e.

```
 async registerTeam(team) {
    const response = await this.api.post('NewTeam', team).toPromise();
    return response
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't allow me to do like that. In _api.service.ts_ I modified _post_: `async post(route: any, postData: any) {
    return await this.http.post(this.global.urlAPI + route, postData, await this.getHeaders()).toPromise();
  }` but then I don't know how to subcribe to that... it doesn't allow me, only I can use _then_ but doesn't work... in _new.page.ts_: `async registerTeam(form){.... this.teamsService.registerTeam(postData).then((val => {
      this.router.navigate(['/members/teams']);
    }));}`

Comment: Can you put your code in a stackblitz to help debug?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work.... Also it connects to an api I'm also developing...

Comment: can you create a minimal stackblitz for the code? Everything should be possible via async/await and promises, so I'm guessing there's just a small error somewhere

Comment: I thought that! That this can be done with async/wait... but I don't figure how... I'll try to put something in stackblitz...

Comment: This is done with async await, but at some point you have to convert the observable into a promise to use async await. But if you put a stackblitz together happy to look at it

Comment: I can give you access to the repository in GitHub if you want... let me know, I´ll try also stackblitz. Thanks!

Comment: stackblitz is probably easiest because then there isn't as much additional code to worry about, but otherwise you could use https://codesandbox.io which can link directly to a github repo

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this 
Set your variable as

```
teams: Observable<any>;
```

Step 1: Make a function to get data from POST request in your page.ts file

```
async registerTeam(form: NgForm) {
    let postData = new FormData();
    let birthDate = this.datepipe.transform(form.dateOfBirth, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    postData.append('name',form.name);
    postData.append('description',form.description);
    postData.append('hat','0');
    postData.append('birth',birthDate);
    //Show loading
    /*const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      animated: true,
      spinner: 'circles',
      cssClass: 'custom-loader-class',
      translucent: true
    });
    await loading.present();*/
    await this.teamsService.registerTeam(postData)
     .subscribe(res => {
       //loading.dismiss();   // dismiss loading controller

       if (res.status === true) // check your status 
       {
         this.teams = res;
       }
       else
       {
         alert(res.message) // show alert when no data response from server.
       }
     }, err => {
       loading.dismiss(); // dismiss loading controller
       console.log('$$ERROR$$ '+ JSON.stringify(err));
       alert('Something went wrong. Please try again later.') // Error from server.
}
```

Step 3: Then in your service.ts file , get data from server.

```
  registerTeam(data): Observable<any> {
    const postUrl = this.global.urlAPI + 'your route'; // Make a correct URl to get response from server.
    return this.http.post<any>(postUrl,data) //Post method with params and PostUrl
    .timeout(20000)
    .pipe(
      map(results => results)
    );
  }
```

On side , You should import these necessary components in your service.ts file :

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders , HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';
```

And in your page.ts file :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

**For Headers**

```
//import httpheader in your page.ts file 

    import { HttpHeaders , HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

    //In app.module.ts file
    import { HttpClientModule ,HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
   // In your @ngModule in imports: section add this httpclientmodule.

    imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot({
        }, HttpClientModule]
```

// Then in your post method you can use headers along with your post data

```
    // create a variable for httpOptions

    const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

          headers.append('Token', this.Token); //stored token in a variable or directly append your token here.

           headers.append('id', this.ID);
         };

    // sent this header and your token along with the post request.
```

Comment: trying to do this... the only thing is that I need the headers for the _post_. I've a _getHeaders_ that is _async_ because it gets a token from storage... don't know how to add that, to the post call you do here... (also, the `timeout(20000)` doesn't work)

Comment: @carlonchoboy For headers you can import https headers in your page.ts file as
import { HttpHeaders , HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http'; 
and then you can use header by taking a variable like :
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};
See updated answer for more clarification.

Comment: @carlonchoboy For the Timeout problem You have to import rxjs timeout operator as -
import 'rxjs/add/operator/timeout'; and this - 
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Thanks! The problem with _timeout_ is that it says: _Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'_. With the headers, I have a function (is in the post) that create the headers. The thing this function is async, so I got problem to add to what you're saying. I'm trying to do it.